# jQuery, ajax POST method error : Not Found

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**my script code:**

```
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
        var pageUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("`/TestPage.aspx/SystemEdit")%>';
        var ip = $('#editIP').text();
        var loc = $('#txtBay').val();
        var team = $('#txtTeam').val();
        var port = $('#txtPort').val();
        var xcel = "", office = "", moni = "";                                   
        var parameter={ "ip": ip, "loc": loc, "team": team, "port": port, "excel": xcel, "office": office, "monitor": moni}

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: pageUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
            contentType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data,success,error) {
                alert("Error:" +error);
            }
        });           
    });
```

my code behind c# code is:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SystemEdit(string ip, string loc,string team, string port, string excel,string office, string monitor)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return "success";
}
```

my page name is : **TestPage.aspx**

While clicking the save button I'm getting '**Not Found**' Error.

Comment: Fire up network tab of your browser or use fiddler to see what's the request url. At the moment I see one typo in your code var pageUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("`/TestPage.aspx/SystemEdit")%>'; do you see "`" before /TestPage.aspx" ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot. It's a type mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check following things:

```
1. your static method not including [webmethod] attribute.
2. your url is incorrect(change "`/TestPage.aspx/SystemEdit" to   
   "~/TestPage.aspx/SystemEdit")
3. is your save button is server side or client side.
i hope it helps you
```